# Blender 2.80 Multiple Quick Selections in Outliner

Tags: collections

In Blender 2.8 Outliner, what is the best way to quickly select many items that are in a row and without individually clicking on each item? Shift+Left Mouse Click or CTRL-Shift+Left Mouse Click does not work.

Like in the below image, want to select quickly all items between the first and last selected.

[image]

Comment: "*what am I missing here?*" That fact that 2.8 is barely into beta and not finished yet

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unfinished features in experimental Blender

Comment: You had probably better rename this as 'Blender Stack for up to 2.79c only then!' As it turns out there is a perfectly good work around suggested so closing the question would not have bought that to light.

Comment: I thought that the question was perfectly valid as V2.79b to date still does not have this Shift+Click multiple selection and 2.80 lacks it as well. Hopefully at least it will be implemented as CTRL+Shift+Click just like selecting a sequence of multiple images for the video editor insertion in Blender for a time laps video.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a feature request.

Comment: Right click on collection-> Select Objects -> (objects should now be highlighted in viewport)

Answer (score 6):

I thought I update my post so the latest selection feature is in here as well.

Now blender allows the windows type of selection by clicking on the first item to be selected in the outline and scrolling to the last item of the selection sequence and holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> down and <kbd>Left Click</kbd> on the last item. All the object will be selected between the first and last selected items this way.

***Original answer below which was the only valid way of selecting multiple items at the time of original posting but it is still a valid selection process as well:***

The fastest way I found is pressing <kbd>B</kbd> on the keyboard for Box Select and select and drag a box, with the left mouse button, around the required items. You can add more to the selection by scrolling, if you have more to add that is not visible on the screen, and pressing <kbd>B</kbd> and selecting more items again.
It still can take a while if you have a 100 or so items to select but currently the fastest, unless someone knows another better way.
This may change, as 2.80 is still in beta, but currently that is how you can select consecutive objects faster in the Outliner.